# Using vi, how can I remove all lines that contain [searchterm]?

Tags: css, regex, vim

I want to remove all lines in a CSS file that contain the word "color".

This would include:

```
body {background-color:#000;}
div {color:#fff;}
```

How would you do that using the :%s/ command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that such a wise idea? You could end up doing something you don't want if your CSS has sections like this

```
body {background-color: #000;
  font-size: large;
}

p {
  color: #fff; float: left;
  }
```

You're better off removing only the properties containing color

`s/\(\w\|-\)*color\w*\s*:.\{-}\(;\|$\)//`

**Update:** 
As too_much_php pointed out, the regex I didn't exactly work. I've fixed it, but it requires vim. It isn't feasible to forge a regex that only removes problem properties in vi. Because there are no character classes, you would have to do something like replacing the \w with `\(a\|b\|c\|d\|....\Z\)`

Comment: But that regex doesn't work in vim! It doesn't even work in Perl.

Answer (score 12):

Should just be

```
:g/color/d
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard ex sequence:

```
  :/color/d
```

Answer (score 2):

And just to give you a completely different answer:

```
:%!grep -v color
```

:)

This alludes to a larger bit of functionality; you can apply your knowledge of *nix commandline filters to editing your code.  Want a list of enums sorted alphabetically?  Visual select, `:!sort` and it's done.

You can use `uniq`, `tac`, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
:%s/.*color.*\n//
```